# How to use the checked() function to check for a non-empty var

Tags: php, functions, html

I was wondering if it's possible to convert the following line:

```
echo ( !empty( $var ) ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
```

to one using the `checked()` function in WordPress:

```
checked( $var, <<don't know what to put here>> );
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. You may do both, but may not be as optimal as single line:

```
$verify = (empty($var)) ? 'current_value' : $var;
checked( $verify, $current );
```

Or you can create a custom function:

```
function better_checked($check, $current, $echo = true) {

     $result = ' checked="checked"';

     if ( ( $check != '' && $current != '' ) && ( (string) $check !== (string) $current ) )
          $result = '';

     if ($echo)
          echo $result;

     return $result;

}
```